# Who typically administers the continuous integration server?

Tags: continuous-integration

I administer my company's continuous integration server and build farm. I support around 50 other developers in addition to performing my main duties as a software developer. Software development takes priority, and lately I've had difficulty finding time to support or enhance the server.

I imagine that someone with an IT and software development background could be employed full-time as a "DevOps engineer" for this task, and support all of our other developer tools as well.

Is this role typically fulfilled by DevOps? How large does a company need to be in order to support someone in this position full-time?

Comment: This *really* isn't a Server Fault question - there's absolutely nothing *technical* about it, you're asking a "how do we manage our [workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) and staff?" question. The answer is "The job is done by a qualified, competent person with sufficient time to *do the job*." -- If you're the only qualified, competent person and you don't have time to do the job it's time to add staff or remove some of your workload...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seriously I would hire someone. But I would make sure he also contributes to the dev team in a critical position.

Build is more than maintaining the build server (scripts, deployment etc. comes into that too) and then there is the one thing that few developers know an most admins know better: INSTALLATION, so that guy can also be the dev in charge of the software installers, as well as a admin for the development machines. PLENTY of work for 1 person for 50 developers.